# Making a success or error message after submitting image via form?

Tags: php, html, forms, message, display

i'm really new to html and php. I'm trying to get a form working, which is used to upload pictures to a server.

```
<form class="myBtn" id="Upload" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="visibility:hidden;"><br>
      Select template to upload:<br>
         <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"><br>
         <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

This is my form in HTML.

```
<?php $target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$needheight = 355;
$needwidth = 275;

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "Checked: File is an image! - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "Checked: File is not an image!";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}

if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 1048576) {
  echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
if($imageFileType != "png") {
    echo "Sorry, only .PNG is allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
}

else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "Your cape template". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your template. Try again.";
    }
}

?>
```

Here you can see my php code. I'm really sorry that its such a WoC (wall of code) but I dont really know which specific parts of the code you need to help me.

I got the php working which took me ages, but I did it. I can successfully upload templates to my server.
But at the moment, after successfully submitting a template, I'll get redirected to another blank page showing:
"Checked: File is an image! - image/png! Your cape template has been uploaded!"

Is there a way not to redirect to a blank page but show a success or error echo right on the main website?

Thank you alot, I'm stuck at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Remove action from your form so page will post on same page. And befoe your 
html `<form>` write the code from php which is currently in `upload.php`

```
<?php $target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$needheight = 355;
$needwidth = 275;

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "Checked: File is an image! - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "Checked: File is not an image!";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}

if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 1048576) {
  echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
if($imageFileType != "png") {
    echo "Sorry, only .PNG is allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
}

else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "Your cape template". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your template. Try again.";
    }
}

?>

<form class="myBtn" id="Upload" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="visibility:hidden;"><br>
      Select template to upload:<br>
         <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"><br>
         <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I moved the php code into my html right above the form and removed the action="". Its written in completely white text. Is this normal? (using sublime).

If I try to upload a picture, it refreshes the webpage (no redirection anymore) but does not upload.

Comment: Hope your file extension is `.php` and not `.html`

Comment: What specific file extension? I'm a total beginnder in html and php?

Comment: Is your file saved with `index.php` or `index.html`?

Comment: My file is saved as index.html.

Comment: Changed it to index.php. The page reloads after submitting but no php echo is displayed nor the files get uploaded.

Comment: Update! I'm stupid. I just needed to relog with my ftp data. The upload works, only the messages wont be displayed.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Your issue is solved or not? If not then I have updated my answer.try it

Comment: One part is solved. I'm not getting redirected to another page and I can upload templates, but i'm still lacking the notification messages. They do not appear. 

I can't see where you have changed/updated your code. :/

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do something like this - keep all the code on one page and display the relevant message after the form has been submitted.

```
<?php


    $errors=array();
    $allowed=array('png');
    $message = false;

    /* A utility function to report actual error ( if any ) */
    function uploaderror( $code ){ 
        switch( $code ) { 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE: return "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini"; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE: return "The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form"; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL: return "The uploaded file was only partially uploaded"; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE: return "No file was uploaded"; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR: return "Missing a temporary folder"; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE: return "Failed to write file to disk"; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION: return "File upload stopped by extension"; 
            default: return "Unknown upload error";
        }
    }


    /* Only process this if these condition are met */
    if( isset( $_POST['submit'], $_FILES['fileToUpload'] ) ) {

        /* Obtain reference to upload - Object notation is quicker/easier imo */
        $obj=(object)$_FILES['fileToUpload'];
        $name=$obj->name;
        $tmp=$obj->tmp_name;
        $size=$obj->size;
        $type=$obj->type;
        $error=$obj->error;

        /* configuration */
        $target_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploads/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . $name;
        $ext = strtolower( pathinfo( $name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) );
        $needheight = 355;
        $needwidth = 275;




        if( $error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK && is_uploaded_file( $tmp ) ){
            /* Is it an image */
            $check = getimagesize( $tmp );
            if( !$check )$errors[]='Checked: File is not an image!';
            else{
                /* Find dimensions and other attributes */
                list( $width, $height, $type, $attr ) = $check;
                if( $width < $needwidth or $height < $needheight )$errors[]='Image is too small';
            }

            if( file_exists( $target_file ) )$errors[]='Sorry, that file already exists.';
            if( $size > 1048576 ) $errors[]='Sorry, your file is too large.';
            if( !in_array( $ext, $allowed ) ) $errors[]='Sorry, only images of type .'.strtoupper( implode( ', .',$allowed ) ).' '.(count($allowed)==1 ? 'is' : 'are').' allowed.';


            clearstatcache();


            if( empty( $errors ) ){
                $status = move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $target_file );
                $message = $status ? "Your cape template ". basename( $name ). " has been uploaded." : "Sorry, there was an error uploading your template. Try again.";
            }           

        } else {
            exit( uploaderror( $error ) );
        }
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>File upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form class='myBtn' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            Select template to upload:<br>
            <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
        </form>
        <?php
            if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $message ) ){
                echo $message;
            }
            if( !empty( $errors ) ){
                foreach( $errors as $error ) echo $error . '<br />';
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Should I add my php code right infront of the <form></form> or even above the <!doctype html>?

Comment: You should be able to run the above code as it is - with the php before the doctype declaration

Answer (score 0):

Glad u completed the PHP part by urself. you have used two files one for HTML and for PHP make it as one file and make use of $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].

```
<form class="myBtn" id="Upload" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><br>
 <label>Select template to upload:</label><br>
     <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"><br>
     <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

<?php 
$message = "";
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$target_dir = "/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$needheight = 355;
$needwidth = 275;
$check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
if($check !== false) {
    echo $message = "Checked: File is an image! - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
} else {
    echo $message = "Checked: File is not an image!";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
echo $message ="Sorry, file already exists.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 1048576) {
echo $message ="Sorry, your file is too large.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
if($imageFileType != "png") {
echo $message ="Sorry, only .PNG is allowed.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}

if ($uploadOk == 0) {
echo $message ="Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
}

else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
echo $message ="Your cape template". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
echo $message ="Sorry, there was an error uploading your template. Try again.";
}
}
}
?>

<script>
var alert_msg = "<?php echo $message; ?>";
<?php if(strlen($message) > 1) { ?>
alert(alert_msg);
<?php } ?>
</script>
```

I used alert to show your status messages. Hope it works.

and please remove the hidden style in your form.( why did it come there).

Comment: Hey. I tried your code, but it seems like its broken. It's not recognized as php and displayed as text on the website. Tried it as .html and .php.

Comment: while saving the file please set the file format to all files and add file extension as .php . It seems the file u saved will be in example.txt.php, or the file is not placed in localhost(server) folder.

Comment: Hey, I'm using sublime and saved my index as index.php and index.html. Both did not work. But I implemented your code directly into my main page.  I'm directly testing via a server i can acces to per domain, no localhost.

Comment: any idea how to slove this problem?